# set orientation of transparent activity to differ from that of parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, android-orientation

Given AlphaActivity and BravoActivity. BravoActivity is started by AlphaActivity as

```
startActivity(new Intent(AlphaActivity.this,BravoActivity.class));
```

in `onCreate` AlphaActivity has the line

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

For BravoActivity, the `onCreate` method has a similar but different call

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

The catch is: BravoActivity is a transparent activity. So my desired design is that AlphaActivity should remain in LANDSCAPE orientation while BravoActivity remains in PORTRAIT orientation. How do I accomplish this?

Right now, as soon as BravoActivity starts, the orientation of AlphaActivity changes to PORTRAIT - I don't want that. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that what you want isn't going to be possible, but that's just a guess. Assuming `AlphaActivity` is not using a `SurfaceView` or something like that, a backup plan would be to capture the contents of `AlphaActivity` as a `Bitmap` and use that as the background of `BravoActivity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, You are pretty insightful there: Yes, AlphaActivity is using a SurfaceView. And the orientation flip distorts what is seen through it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

> android:screenOrientation="nosensor"

to yours `Activity` in `manifest.xml`

**UPD_0:**

Try also to override `onConfigurationChanged`. My idea - it may called when yours activity start to change orientation and you could set yours desired orientation instead of what system desired)

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.YOURS_DESIRED_ORIENTATION);
}
```

Comment: this didn't do it. nice idea, though.